# ActionUrl in ASP.NET MVC Preview 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I don't need a Link but rather only the href= part of the ActionLink.

But if I call Html.ActionLink(...) I get a  back. 
Is there a way to just return the URL of the Action while not getting the ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MVC also provides a UrlHelper class which can do the same thing:

```
<%=Url.Action(actionName)%>
<%=Url.Action(actionName, htmlValues)%>
<%=Url.Action(actionName, controllerName, htmlValues)%>
```

Comment: Awesome, this is what I've been searching for! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Edit: in response to commment, now including parameters:

```
<% =Html.BuildUrlFromExpression<YourController>(c => c.YourAction(parameter)) %>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of how to use the BuildUrlFromExpression(...) Method?
I can't get the parameters right. maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Wondering how you could add a parameter that's not required by the Controller Action (eg. I'm using a URL like: Article/<id>/<otherId>/<articleName> .. The ArticleName is just for SEO and has no meaning to my Controller. So I just ignore it. With the BuildUrlFromExpression stuff I can't include it..